# Error creating Scratch Org - The Streaming request failed to handshake

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm trying to create a scratch org using either VS Code or the command line.  I'm able authenticate to my dev org using:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login
```

This works correctly.  However when I try to create a scratch org:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias HelloWorld --setdefaultusername
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  The streaming request failed to handshake at https://<dev org name>.my.salesforce.com/cometd/44.0.
```

I am behind a corporate proxy and initially could not even authenticate my dev org until I set the proxy environment variables and their npm equivalents.  I also currently have sslVerify and strict-ssl set to false.

Comment: Did the scratch org get created, and just not registered locally, or if you look in your dev hub, is there no active scratch org at all?

Comment: I double checked and there are no active scratch orgs after running the command.  I ran "sfdx force:org:list" and also checked the Active Scratch Orgs tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to figure out what was wrong by trial and error.  It turns out that I had an error in my HTTPS_PROXY environment variable.  Once I corrected it, I was able to create my scratch org and proceed.

In the end, I didn't need the sslVerify and strict-ssl npm setttings.  Just the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables set correctly.